Does a Pakistani passport holder, wife of a British citizen, need a visa for Schengen countries? If yes, what documents are needed?
Pakistani passport holder,wife of a British citizen living on a spouse visa in UK. Does she need visa for Schengen countries? If yes, what documents are needed ?
I have few scenarios:

Husband and British daughter age 1 year is traveling with her.

Husband isn't travelling, but daughter is traveling.

Can she apply through embassy directly or does she need to apply through VFS?



Since the UK left the EU, being married to a British citizen has no impact on the visa requirements for a Pakistani citizen traveling to the Schengen area.  Neither does being the parent of a British citizen, nor residence in the UK, nor possession of a UK visa.
Whether you will have to apply through VFS (or another third-party processor) or directly at an embassy or consulate depends on the country to which you are applying; the country you need to apply to depends on your planned itinerary and possibly on the reason for your trip.

(+1) The OP can find out here if they have to / can apply through VFS

Yes, you need a visa. The UK was never part of the Schengen area.
For Schengen states, you are a Pakistani applying on a Pakistani passport. The procedure will depend on the country to which you will apply (where you're visiting first or where you will spend the most time) and where you're applying from.
Your British visa and residence, marriage to a UK national, and daughter will only help establish your family ties to leave the Schengen area when seeking a visa but does not exempt you from needing a visa.

Yes, you definitely need a visa to visit the EU regardless of the passport of your spouse and daughter. Regarding the visa process, you need to apply through the visa application website of the country where you want to visit first in the EU/Schengen region. At the end of the filling up the applications, you get checklist containing a list of documents you need to submit. As a rule of thumb, you cannot visit the embassy directly to apply for the visa, so you would need to visit VFS to submit those documents.

"you need to apply through the visa application website of the country where you want to visit first in the EU/Schengen region": this is incorrect.  You must apply based on your main destination; only if no main destination can be determined is the first country of entry relevant.  See for example At which embassy should I apply for a Schengen visa when staying a few days in several countries?, though that is only one of what must be dozens of questions and answers here on the subject.

I think most of the people are confused (being less implied) by the country of first visit vs the main destination. My definition of the country of first visit is the country where you exit the airport without intention of transit. And this is what I want to point out in my answer. Main destinations can be many but first destination is always one. Correct me if I am wrong.

Yes you are wrong. If your main destination in days spend there and/or reason to visit is a different one from the one you enter you need to apply at the country of the main destination.

Look, suppose you're going to the Schengen area for six weeks as a tourist, spending one week in France, one week in Spain, three weeks in Germany, and one week in Austria, in that order.  The rules are very clear that the visa application for this itinerary must be submitted to Germany.  According to this answer, the application should be submitted to France.  That is why this answer is incorrect.
